# « Parmi la population la plus riche, seulE/S 20% est ... »

Tags: accord, nombres, noms-collectifs

Est-ce « seule » (la population) ou « seuls » (20% des individus) dans cette phrase ?

Comment: Tu réponds toi-même à ta question en utilisant "est": "seule 20% est"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Parmi la population la plus riche, **seuls** 20% **sont** ...

Ici, il faut différencier ce qu'il y a avant la virgule et après.

Si dans la première proposition, c'est de *la population* dont on parle, dans la deuxième, ce sont bien *les 20%* qui sont à l'honneur !

Le *seul* s'accordera avec le sujet de la proposition dans laquelle il se trouve.

Comme par exemple, dans la phrase "parmi la population, seules les femmes..."

La seule chose qui s'accorde avec *la population* ici est l'adjectif "riche", qui ne marque hélas pas la différence entre masculin et féminin.

**EDIT :**
En fait ça va surtout dépendre de ce qui va venir après les 20%. Tu peux choisir d'accorder avec le complément qui suivra ou d'accorder selon le genre et le nombre de "20%". Dans ta phrase tu continues avec "est", donc le *seul* devrait plut^ot s'accorder au singulier mais le genre dépendra du complément

Comment: Donc si je vous suis : 
- "parmi la population, seule 12% a quelque chose"
- "Si le principe est soutenu par 17% de la population, seule environ 40% de la population accepte quelque chose."
- "En 2015, 15% des gens affirmaient quelque chose; en 2016, seuls 12% affirment avoir changé d'avis."
- "Seules 11% des personnes ont changé d'avis."

Comment: Oui, tous tes exemples me semblent correct !

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce genre de cas (qualification d'une partie d'un ensemble), on peut accorder grammaticalement soit avec la partie, soit avec le tout. Mais il faut être cohérent.

> Parmi la population la plus riche, seul**e** 20% **est** visé**e** par la proposition de loi.
>   Parmi la population la plus riche, seul**s** 20% **sont** visé**s** par la proposition de loi.

Ici la partie est au pluriel (20% est pluriel puisque c'est 20 quelque chose), et l'ensemble est au singulier (la population). On rencontre cette situation plus souvent dans le sens contraire: une partie au singulier d'un tout pluriel, par exemple « la plupart des gens », « un cinquième des habitants », etc.